# How can I preserve the values when the page is loaded first time on the edit link click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one page on which I am showing grid model with edit links in MVC. Now on click of that edit link we are getting redirected to other page. On that page I have 4 buttons, on the click on that buttons grid model is shown.

how I can preserve the values when the page is first time loaded when we click on the edit link in jquery?

Comment: use cookies or session to preserve your respective values

Comment: Thank  you - ameenulla0007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localstorage to save your formData and then when your next page loads you can use the data from localstorage.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: I have voted your answer but its not allowing me as I am new to this site and don't have 15 reputations to show my vote publically. Your anwer is really helped me.. thank you..

Comment: yeah but you can still mark it as accepted answer. Plus by doing so you earn some reputation points